# Cannot resolve symbol 'getAudioInputStream'

Tags: java, swing, audio, compiler-errors, javasound

".getAudioInputStream(file)" give the error "cannot resolve symbol" (IDE Intellij, java 8)

I try the solution in File > Invalidate Chaces / Restart ... but it doesn't work

```
package com.Main;

import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;

public class SoundEffect {

    private String filepath;
    private Clip clip;

    public SoundEffect(String filepath) {
        this.filepath = filepath;
        try {
            File file = new File(filepath);
            AudioInputStream sound = new AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(sound);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    public void play() {
        clip.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AudioInputStream sound = new AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
```

You don't want to create an instance of an object. You want to invoke a static method of a class.

You don't need the "new".

The code should be:

```
//AudioInputStream sound = new AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
```